# How does google know my iPhone device name?

Tags: account-security, multi-factor

I have just signed into google using my browser, and google  two step authentication has just started. When signing into google on my browser, it informed me that an authentication had been sent to my YouTube app on Rich’s iPhone.

How does google know the name of my device? I don’t believe this is included in the user agent string?

Answer (score 1):

> When signing into google on my browser, it informed me that an authentication had been sent to my YouTube app on Rich’s iPhone.

If you're logged in to the Youtube app on the phone in question the app can read your phone's name.

In [iOS <=15 this required no permissions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620015-name). In iOS >15 [it requires permission and must meet some criteria](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_developer_device-information_user-assigned-device-name).

Google probably claims they need it for multi-device features - such as the one you experienced.

Comment: Hey Vidarlo thanks for the answer. So youtube(google) are able to draw such data from my iPhone about section and this is just transmitted to them during app usage?

Comment: Yes. I thought that was rather obvious? The purpose is probably what you experience - so they can tell you what device they send the information to...